# wxpython: automatically resize a static image (staticbitmap) to fit into size

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

My wxPython project has a frame, with multiple nested sizers.

One of the sizers contains a wxStaticImage with a bitmap that is read from a file.

I need the image to resize (grow/shrink) every time the frame is resized, so it will fit it's sizer's boundaries.

(I think that) I know how to resize an image. What I **don't know** is how to:

- how to get the image's container's width or height?
- maybe i overlooked a property that does it auotmatically?

(for now, I don't mind the proportions)

**Edit: Complete solution**

1. i understood wrong about wxStaticBitmapin.Size. it does NOT describe the size of the **image** (i.e. image resolution), but rather - wxStaticBitmapin.Size gives the **sizer's slot dimentions**, or in other words: the current widget's size.

   so with Mik's code i now how to fit into the slot.
2. in addition to mike's solution: when using onSize event on a frame, don't forget to add **event.skip()**. otherwise the sizers will stop re-aligning. Altertanively, just use the image's onSize.

here's the complete event method:

```
def bitmap1_onSize(self, e=None):
    W, H = self.bitmap1.Size
    if W > H:
        NewW = W
        NewH = W * H / W
    else:
        NewH = H
        NewW = H * W / H
    img = wx.Image(self.frame_file_picker.Path, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
    img = img.Scale(NewW,NewH)
    self.bitmap1.SetBitmap(wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
    e.Skip()
```

Comment: I am wondering that there is now derived class which implements this. This use case isn't so unusual I think.

Comment: Those formulas don't look correct to me.  Your NewW and NewH both end up the same value (the greater of H, W) and define a square image.  e.g. The formula W*H/W will just end up with H.

Comment: I really have no clue about 7 years old code -- but -- it seems to me syntactic sugar of some sort.  (I wrote this code well after fourth grade, so it wasn't ignorance of  basic math. I hope.).  BTW if you ended up here in 2020, does that mean this feature is still not built-in wx?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to catch EVT_SIZE or EVT_SIZING. You can check out this tutorial I wrote about creating an image viewer. It has some scaling code in it: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/

I would just take that scaling code and use it to update your image. You'll want to make sure you stop scaling your image up past its maximum size or you'll end up with a lot of pixelization though.